# Mongoose middleware arguments are not passed when deployed on Bluemix

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ibm-cloud

I am working on a node app with mongoose connectivity to mongodb. I am using mongoose middleware for modifying the data before saving like:

```
myschema.pre('save',function(next) {
   ....... // modfy data here
   next();
})
```

Everything goes smoothly and the save call is always successful. But, I am now deploying the app on Bluemix and it gives the following error on a save call:

```
Error : Your pre must have a next argument -- e.g., function (next, ...)
```

I don't know why this error is generated when I have already used the `next` argument and it does well everywhere else.

Comment: Are you using the MongoDB by Compose service?

Comment: Or probably a version mismatch of various modules between Bluemix and local?